# Deploy IIS 7.5 websites on other machines while maintaining IIS7.5 Settings

Tags: deployment, iis-7, settings, inno-setup

I have 5 ASP.NET Web Applications that I need to distribute to client machines. I am using Inno Setup to package and dump them into directories and batch scripts to create Virtual Sites and Directories.

Unfortunately, during testing, I keep running into issues with IIS 7.5 rather than the applications themselves. These issues are rather painful to pinpoint and usually involve the fact that IIS 7.5 configurations, settings, handlers, ISAPI modules etc... aren't the same across machines.

All web applications are working fine on my current machine (and a few other development ones). **Is there some easy process to say export IIS 7.5 settings and import them to deployment machines?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a good way to do it easy.  We currently use powershell to setup IIS with the correct settings for IIS 7+ on 6 we used the export functionality in inetmgr.